# Find element in selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with C# to run some tests. I have an issue with an element which i can not locate. I know it is there, and I have it in html. even knowing everything about it, i can not seem to find it. When I used nodeJS it was pretty easy to locate, but in C# I just can not. After trying so many things, I thought I would ask here.

I get OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException when using the following:

`IWebElement Title = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(., 'TextHere')]"));`

I tried using the css path, xpath and tag, but the only case where I even found something was with tag. And it was not the correct element.

Is there just something majorly wrong with my syntax? I have looked at multiple threads about this and all the syntax they used haven't worked either.

Comment: This sounds like "element in an iframe" or "need to wait for asynchronous element".  Without the HTML, it's hard to determine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. The element was inside an iframe. But not only that, it was also being created by a function which ran on load. Meaning i had to put in a delay to wait for it to load.
Here is the working code in case anyone is looking at a similar issue:

```
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("iFrame id")));  
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); 
        IWebElement Title = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("path to element"));
```

Just using sleep might not be optimal, but I am quite new at this, and it works. If someone has a good replacement i would love to hear suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

say or between two calls of contains function

```
//*[contains(text(), 'About us') or contains(text(), 'about us')]
```

or use translate function to make xpath case insensitive

```
//*[contains(translate(text(), 'ABOUTS', 'abouts'), 'about us')]
```

when you are using Contain text make sure the contain text is unique or else you will get list of result and based on your condition iterate it.